# Angularjs - Function start recursive call after calling first time

Tags: angularjs

I have a function with root scope in a controller when i call it first time it start calling himself recursively.

Any Help Plz.

```
$rootScope.getWord = function(key){
    console.log('in get work fucntion key: '+key);
    if(angular.isDefined($rootScope.lang[key])){
        return $rootScope.lang[key];
    } 
    else {
        return key;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sufficient information!  Which directive are you using to bind the function? Share the view code for the same.

Comment: Please put the code where you call this function. As well, avoid as much as possible to attach data to $rootScope, use factories/services instead.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I am using smartAdmin theme. In the view i am calling it by {{ getWord('test') }}.

Comment: The link of the theme is http://sang-shockwave.rhcloud.com/?#/tables/normal

Comment: I figure out that the problem is not of $rootScope. any function call from view start recursive calling himself. e.g  i create  a function in my controller as $scope.testing = function(key){
  console.log('in testing function of add user controller');
  //return $rootScope.getWord(key);
 } and call it from view {{ testing('us') }} so it start recursively calling. console is printing message again and again. Any Help Please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last i find out the issue. One of my directive was called after some interval by settimeout. Due to which again was checking for any change. That's why my function was recursively called. Now i have change the settimeout directive and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid using rootscope in angular , if u really wants to use then follow this way.

consider this as a A.js

```
 var title = "Company";
     $rootScope.$broadcast('changepanelTitle', title);
```

so now this title your are going use in diffrent controller consider This is B.js

```
 $scope.$on('changepanelTitle', function(event, title) {
         $scope.paneltitle = title;
    });
```

Comment: Yes that is, But this is in normal case. While i am using it for getting translation of the key. As this theme support multi languages. The content used in any view should be get via this getWord method implemented with $rootScop.